# Как сделать переход

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Как сделать, чтобы при swipe navigation bar вниз, был переход на главный view controller

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Не совсем понял вопрос, вам нужно чтобы при скроле таблицы вниз переходило на главный вьюконтроллер?

Comment: При скроле navigation bar вниз, нужно переходить в главный экран